# Applying Json Styles to Google Map Iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to apply json style for Google Map API to the embedded iframe? I want to show my business's Google Map pin with all the details, directions, etc. But I would also like to style the map to match aesthetics of the website.

I feel like the only way I can get the full google maps experience with all the businesses and info is with the iframe, but the only way I can style map is with the API.

Is there a way to add the styles to the URI in the iframe src?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look to be possible.  If you want to style the map, you need to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (at least at this point).